# Is legal to requestion an old question that I've answered?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I've answered a question made more than a year ago.  Reading it leads me to wonder about a more broad question that even I have had. Is appropriate to ask this new broader question myself and post the same answer to it?

Comment: Can you post a reference?

Comment: Well, I can post an example but I think maybe its not the right one. I just can say that the question came to my mind answering [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676796/embed-matplotlib-widget-in-multiple-places/20615277#20615277) but I'm not saying that the question is bad or that cannot be edited of course. Maybe others can post here a more precise example :)

Comment: What do you mean by re-question?  Ask the question again, rephrase the question to change its scope?

Comment: More or less, but the key idea is using the same answer

Comment: @xndrme That's not clear at all.  Which are you asking about?

Comment: I'm saying asking a new question and posting it with the same answer. Maybe it includes the previous question as subcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose of editing the question is to clarify it against an already-posted answer, I'd say that's OK.  It should probably be the highest-voted or accepted answer, though.

If the purpose of editing the question is to re-purpose it, changing it enough to make it a different question, it's almost always better to post a new question, and answer it with the same answer, but custom-tailored for the new question.

Comment: didn't I get into a small debate with you the other day where you said that you shouldn't be reposting answers in the first place?

Comment: Not copy-paste answers.  Note that I specifically stated that the new answer should be custom-tailored for the new question, and that's most likely the same clarification I gave you before.

Comment: But what if you think that the question could be better and start editing but then you realize that you are changing a lot and decide that is better a new question that perfectly fits your EXACTLY answer.

Comment: A highly unlikely scenario.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm wrong of course and is a matter of personal taste, but I've seem a lot of questions with really great answers that can be in a better question. Note: when I say a better question I'm not saying that the asker is wrong is just that maybe is better another question for the principle of great question with great answers.

Comment: Then make the question better by editing.  But don't change it into a different question; that's not a good approach.